# Inner class generics - Incompatible types

Tags: java, generics, incompatibletypeerror

i just can't seem to get why i get that these are incompatible types, is it just bc they are on different class levels? I just can't quite get why.

```
public class PrependLinearListImpl<T>{
    private Node<T> first;

    private class Node<T> {
        private T head;
        private Node<T> tail;
        Node(T head) {
            this.head = head;
            this.tail = first;
            first = this;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: You have two different `T`s.

Comment: Hi, somehow i thought that the inner class T was the exact same as the Outer class one, should i just rename it to "E" and make it an extension of "T"? The error is the following: Incompatible types. Required: PrependLinearListImpl.Node<T> Found: PrependLinearListImpl.Node<T>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `PrependLinearListImpl<T>.Node` already inherits the generic argument from its outer class. It's not necessary to redefine the generic component.

The following should work as-is:

```
public class PrependLinearListImpl<T>{
    private Node first;

    private class Node {
        private T head;
        private Node tail;
        Node(T head) {
            this.head = head;
            this.tail = first;
            first = this;
        }
    }

}
```

If `Node` were `static`, then it would be necessary to provide its own generic parameter.